# Create dualboot with existing Windows raid array by adding SSD

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, raid

I currently have a 3-disk RAID 0 array with Windows 10 installed.  The array is a hardware array via my MSI motherboard.

I would like to add a new blank SSD drive with K/Ubuntu on it, and have that boot first so I can have grub dualboot either system.  I would prefer the Windows RAID array remain untouched in case I have to go back to my current setup.

I have done this before with drives, but not with an existing RAID array.  My concern is that the RAID array might cause problems and I'm not sure what I'll have to do to get things running, and I don't want to lose the array.

I'm looking for advice here, because I have many thousands of documents, home videos and pictures that I have backed up but it's a very very VERY long backup/restore procedure (Almost 1 TB, many small files).  Should I have any concerns or just go ahead and try it?  The distro I have is Kubuntu 15.10 64-bit.

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I booted off of a USB iso and double-checked that the RAID array was being detected and could be mounted properly.  It was, and I was able to access the file structure.

I added the 2nd SDD drive and did the same test again from the Live USB, and could access both the RAID and the SDD.

I went ahead and started the install onto the SDD.  My RAID array was my primary boot drive, sda, and the SDD drive was sdb.  I configured the installation to put grub onto the RAID array (sda) since that's what boots first, and it rebooted and worked perfectly.  It even detected my Windows 10 OS on the RAID array when installing grub, so I'm still able to boot into Windows.  When I boot into Linux, I can also still access the RAID array files.

So, if you can boot off of a stick or DVD to run a Live session and still have access to your RAID array, then it's safe to go ahead and install since you already know that it can use your RAID, and grub will be able to find it and boot into it.